# What is the name of people who do algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

People who do topology is called topologists, 
people who do analysis is called analysts,
people who do geometry is called geometers,
then how about algebra?

Comment: algebraists....

Comment: they are called nerds

Answer (score 2):

They are called algebraists...

Comment: Surprisingly, there is a [book named this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Algebraist)!

Comment: Also, there is a book named [The Physicists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Physicists). No book about topologists, though.